# Using the Replace function

Tags: replacement

How can I replace two variables at once with Replace[] ? Can't find how to do this. I tried

```
Replace[x^2+y^2, {x -> a, y -> b}]
```

but does not work...

Comment: `Replace[x^2 + y^2, {x -> a, y -> b}, 2]`?

Comment: You could also use `ReplaceAll`: `ReplaceAll[x^2 + y^2, {x -> a, y -> b}]`. It is worth reading the documentation for these two functions to see how they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right lines with `Replace`, but I would rather use a List of replacement rules to achieve this; as mentioned in comments, this is contained in a function called `ReplaceAll`. You can define your desired original polynomial, and then act on it using `/.` to replace things as desired. In your case, I would write something like:

```
x^2+y^2/.{x->a, y->b}
(* a^2+b^2 *)
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. The comments are more often than not a more useful place to start. Have a read of the Generalisations or Examples in documentation and tutorials as well.